# jQuery :contains - exclude matching text in descendants

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

jQuery :contains() selector

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

> The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in
>   any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof.

How can I omit elements that have matching text in any of that element's descendants. I only want to get elements where the matching text appears directly within the selected element.

In the example below I only want spans that contain the word "Red" to have red coloured text.

```
<span>Green
    <span>Red</span>
</span>
<span>Red</span>

jQuery("span:contains('Red')").css("color","red");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UNydR/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
jQuery("span:contains('Red')").filter(function () {
    return ($(this).text() == 'Red')
}).css("color", "red");
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UNydR/3/)**

Comment: This only works for when you want to match against the entire string. I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: This won't work if "Red" is not the entire string in the Div.

Comment: I would change `$(this).text() == 'Red'` to `$(this).text().indexOf('Red') > -1`

Comment: @NeilS - That would return false positives. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/UNydR/8/

Answer (score 3):

jQuery does not provide a built-in way to handle this. You'll have to loop through the child text nodes and search for your string manually:

```
$('span').each(function () {
    var span = this;
    $.each(span.childNodes, function () {
        if (this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf('Red') >= 0 ) {
            $(span).css('color', 'red');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TEnX7/

---

If you find that you use this a lot, and you don't want to have to write that out all the time, you can create your own custom filter expression:

```
jQuery.expr[':']['contains-direct'] = $.expr.createPseudo(function(text) {
    return function (elem) {
        var contains = false;
        $.each(elem.childNodes, function () {
            if (this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf(text) >= 0 ) {
                contains = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        return contains;
    }
});
```

Then you'll be able to use it in your code directly, just like jQuery's `contains`:

```
$('span:contains-direct(Red)').css('color', 'red');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F9xZ8/